# Flutter: New variable from function

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a variable which gets a value from a function. The function generates a random string from a list. However when I call the variable it has the value from the first time it was called. How do I get the variable to call the function every time so it has a new value each time it is called?

My code is:

```
player1gen(List players) {
  //players[Random().nextInt(players.length)];
  return players[Random().nextInt(players.length)].toString();
}

String player1 = player1gen(players);
```

Comment: Can you share mode details like where you declared that function and from where you are calling that one ?

Comment: Is it the same question as your last one?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh it is related to my last question which has now been resolved, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
String get player1 => player1gen(players);
```

Comment: @Entrebear While this does what you want, I would advise against it.  It is unusual for a getter (which to callers looks like a normal variable access) to return different values.  It would be much more *readable* for `player1` to be a function.

Comment: @jamesdlin yeah, I agree